# What's the difference between using rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoop and do save explicitly with spark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I want to save the rdd result to mongodb after spark calculation.

I find there are two ways to do that:

1. Using `rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile`

   ```
   val outputConfig = new Configuration()
   outputConfig.set("mongo.output.uri", "mongodb://mongodb.host.ip:27017/dbName.dbcName")
   outRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("foo",
     classOf[Object],
     classOf[BSONObject],
     classOf[MongoOutputFormat[Object, BSONObject]],
     outputConfig)
   ```
2. Or I can define a `DBCollection` instance and save the rdd via foreach

   ```
    val DBC = new MongoClient("mongodb.host.ip").getDB("dbName").getCollection("dbcName")
    rdd.foreach{
       case (id, data) => {
          val dbo = new BasicDBObject()
          ...code that build the dbObject...
          DBC.save(dbo)
       }
    }
   ```

And I find both the two ways could do the job. But which should I use and why?

Comment: I recommend the new Mongo Spark Connector* (https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/getting-started/#write-to-mongodb) as it should be more idiomatic to how you use Spark.  

However, `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` is fine and will work as expected.  I don't think the foreach method will scale up as each Spark worker will need a MongoClient, so as you add more nodes to your Spark cluster that approach may fail. The MongoDB hadoop connector will handle MongoClient construction and sharing.

* Disclaimer I'm the author

Comment: Thanks @Ross, Mongo Spark Connector seems promising. I will check it out.